# Clarification required about internal error

Tags: here-api

I am using calculate route API to calculate distance and time from origin to destination. Wanted to validate some error codes that I have observed in error code documentation.

One of which is 500 Internal error. 
Description for this says "There is a server configuration issue" can I get a clear reason for cause of this error! What does server configuration Issue mean?!

Answer (score 0):

Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the request.

500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

501 Not Implemented
The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request. This is the appropriate response when the server does not recognize the request method and is not capable of supporting it for any resource.

502 Bad Gateway
The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.

503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

504 Gateway Timeout
The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI (e.g. HTTP, FTP, LDAP) or some other auxiliary server (e.g. DNS) it needed to access in attempting to complete the request.

505 HTTP Version Not Supported
The server does not support, or refuses to support, the HTTP protocol version that was used in the request message. The server is indicating that it is unable or unwilling to complete the request using the same major version as the client, as described in section 3.1, other than with this error message. The response SHOULD contain an entity describing why that version is not supported and what other protocols are supported by that server.